# Plugin in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23, lua-mode

I'm trying to install lua-mode into emacs for windows but nothing seems to be working. I've set my HOME environment variable. I've added `init.el` and `lua-mode.el` to the `HOME\.emacs.d` directory. Then I've added the following code to `init.el`:

```
(autoload 'lua-mode "lua-mode" "Lua editing mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lua$" . lua-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("lua" . lua-mode))

(add-hook 'lua-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock)
```

Nothing is working when I start up emacs and load a .lua file. The major mode is always set to fundamental and there are no other options to change to. What can I do to get this working?

Comment: does `M-x lua-mode` work? What's the value of `load-path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your `init.el` is never read, because you also have a `.emacs` file (or `.emacs.el`) in your $HOME directory. You can choose between those three alternatives for Emacs' init file, but only one of them will be read. Traditionally, that's `.emacs` but some operating systems have problems with that filename syntax.

Also, make sure that you placed `init.el` in your actual home directory, not a directory called "HOME" or something.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) for further details on Emacs init files and [here](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Home_directory#Default_Home_Directory_per_Operating_System) for more info on home directories.

---

If you're not keen on using the `init.el` variant, here are instruction that should make lua-mode work for you using `.emacs`:

1. Start a new Emacs
2. Type `C-x C-f ~/.emacs <ENTER>` (C-x means press CTRL, hold it, press x, release - same for C-f)
3. Insert the following lines:

   > ```
   > (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/lua-mode-dir")
   >
   > (autoload 'lua-mode "lua-mode" "Lua editing mode." t)
   > (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lua$" . lua-mode))
   > (add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("lua" . lua-mode))
   >
   > (add-hook 'lua-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock)
   > ```
4. Type `C-x C-s` to save the buffer to file
5. Type `C-x C-c` to close Emacs

Note that in step 3 you have to adjust "/path/to/lua-mode-dir" with the actual path to the directory where you saved the file lua-mode.el on your hard disk.

Comment: @cschol: It's only one piece in the mosaic. If the missing load-path was the cause of this, the OP would have gotten an error message when opening a .lua file. But since he didn't get an error, it seems that the init.el is never actually loaded.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need something like `(require 'lua-mode)` or something like that? Also make sure that the lua-mode file is in a directory in your `load-path` variable. Something like this before anything else:

> (add-to-list 'load-path "/home/dervin/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")

or wherever, and then the `require`-

Comment: Its almost like emacs isn't even seeing my `init.el` file. Even though I've set HOME and all that. I tried adding that line of code to it pointing to the right folder but it didn't work. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: is this Windows? If so, fire up Emacs, write `M-x pwd` (this will give you the home directory), save your init.el there (or better yet, your .emacs). Another thing you can do: fire up Emacs, load init.el (`C-x C-f`) and then write `M-x eval-buffer` and see what happens. A third thing you can do is start emacs from console and pass the `-u=<path to init.el>` (or `--user=<path to init.el>`) and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The lines look OK. This can depend on a number of things:

- The `init.el` file is not loaded at startup. <strike>In face, this is a non-standard name when it comes to Emacs.</strike> Emacs tries to load the files `~/.emacs`, `~/emacs.el`, and `~/.emacs.d/init.el` in order, and will load the first one found. To verify that you file has loaded, you could add `(message "Loading my init.el")` inside it and check the `*Messages*` buffer.
- The directory where you stored the file `lua-mode.el` is not in the load path. In fact, the `~/.emacs.d` directory is not part of the standard load path.

Comment: It's not true that `init.el` is a non-standard name. Using a `.emacs.d` directory containing an `init.el` is the modern way to keep all of emacs' config files in one directory.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Following this scheme, you can check your entire emacs config into a VC system, like this: http://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/